# how to add a single line in nginx.conf file on ec2 server of elastic beanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, elastic-beanstalk

I would really appreciate a quick fix.

I have deployed laravel app on Docker based single container app environment.

I have pulled the image from ecr.

Attached the rds to the elastic beanstalk app environment.

When i hit the beanstalk url, it leads to the login page which is good.

But when i login it leads me to the dashboard with a 504 bad gateway. Although i hit the dashboard on the url but page does not load.

I ssh into the instance of the elastic beanstalk and went to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and added the line to extend the timeout. The line that added is

"proxy_read_timeout 300s;"

I rerun the service nginx and all gets good.

**Problem**

If i create a new environment in a new app or if in the same environment if a new instance is launched then i have to again do the things with the nginx.conf file by sshing in.

**Required Solution**

I need a custom solution, I have created a .ebextensions folder in which i have tried something on my end. I zipped the .ebextensions folder along the dockerfile and dockerrun.aws.json file and uploaded to the app environment but my file is not working.

I just need to add the "proxy_read_timeout 300s;" line to the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file once the instance is being created to the already present or created file.

Please any one help me asap.

Comment: You would need to include your (obfuscated) ebextensions, Dockefile and dockerrun.aws.json here for review. Its probably that your ebextensions are not being run or are being overwritten. The base image you are using for Nginx will also be relevant.

Comment: Thanks @Garreth McDaid
But I figured it out myself.